# Mistakenly have two logins, would like to consolidate them to one account

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I created a stackoverflow account under one (yahoo) email.  Later I forgot I had used that one and logged in again under another email.  Ideally I'd like to merge my questions, answers, etc. from the second into the first; if I can't do that I would at least like to delete the second and put its email id under the first account.

When I try to add the second email to the first account, the system logs me OUT of the first account and into the second, which is not what I was after.  Is it possible to do what I want, either the first or second option?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Merge user profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) instructions.

> If you have access to both of your accounts, you can merge your duplicate accounts yourself.
>
> 1. Figure out what you use to log into the duplicate account. You can do this by clicking "my logins" above the bio box on your profile page.
>
>    [image]
>
>    Take note of how you're logging into the duplicate account. This is important! You'll need it in the next step.
> 2. Log into your main account. Follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-logins) to add the duplicate account's login to your main account.
> 3. The system should automatically detect that two accounts have the same login and merge them.

Comment: I'm missing something, sorry not to understand or be doing something wrong.  I have one account with a yahoo login, one with a google login.  The yahoo is the one I want to keep, and merge/add the google with/to it.  I log into the yahoo, go to logins, click on add, click on google, and it says "you are logged in, do you want to log out and log in with google; if I click cancel it aborts, if I click ok it logs me into google with no indication it remembers I was logged in with yahoo before.  What am I doing wrong?